# I have issues in selenium webdriver using python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver and using chrome version 77 but i m getting an error

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75.

Comment: Well, it sounds like that version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75. So you'd either need to upgrade Selenium or downgrade Chrome.

Comment: You should really donwload the latest ChromeDriver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, your ChromeDriver supports Chrome version 75 and you are using Chrome 77. You have to keep your ChromeDriver updated to follow the Chrome versions. To update ChromeDriver: [Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

If for any reason you can't download the latest ChromeDriver you could downgrade your Chrome. This link might help for that: [Rollback chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036#rollback)